# Split string and assign first value to a variable in powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

In below example: How do I assign each value to a single variable $var one at a time?

```
$string ="A;B;C"
$Data=$string.split (";")
$Data
A
B
C
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store them in an array with a loop

```
$string ="A;B;C"
$Data=$string.split (";")

$var = @{}
$i = 0
foreach($item in $Data){
    $var[$i] = $item
    $i++
}


$var[0]
$var[1]
$var[2]
```

EDIT: I'm dumb, `$data` is already an array after the string split, you can call out `$data[0]`, that would be your first variable, or:

```
$string ="A;B;C"
$Data=$string.split (";")
$var = $Data[0]
```

Answer (score 5):

You can assign multiple variables when you `split` the string:

```
$string ="A;B;C"
$a, $b, $c = $string -split ';'
# $a  = A
# $b  = B
# $c  = B
```

If you want an array, you already do it right:

```
$string ="A;B;C"
$Data = $string -split ';'
# $Data[0]  = A
# $Data[1]  = B
# $Data[2]  = B
```

As you can see by invoking `$Data.GetType()`, `$Data` is already an `String[]`:

```
IsPublic IsSerial Name     BaseType    
-------- -------- ----     --------    
True     True     String[] System.Array
```

Comment: How do I pass the $dbname array to the backup-sqldatabase  cmdlet? I tried something like below and it throws error

Comment: Error: Array index expression is missing or not valid.

Comment: Code: $dbname=$DBList.split(";")
$i = 0
Foreach($item in $dbname)
{ 
    $dbname[i]=$item

 Backup-Sqldatabase -ServerInstance  $server -Database $dbname[i] -BackupFile $fullbackupfile 
 i++
}

Comment: you have to write `$dbname[$i]`

Answer (score 2):

You can use multiple variables on the left side as well:

```bsh
$string = "A;B;C"
$D1,$D2,$D3 = $string.split(";")
```

Comment: arg, like 5 seconds faster :)

Answer (score 0):

In cases where you you're only truly interested in the *first* output from a string split operation (as the title implies), you can discard the remaining output by assigning it to `$null`:

```
$first,$null = 'A;B;C' -split ';'
```

Since the remaining values are to be discarded anyways, you could ask the `-split` operator to only split once:

```
$first,$null = 'A;B;C' -split ';',2
```

Answer (score 0):

I used below script and it worked.
$dbname=$DBList.split(";")

Foreach($item in $dbname)
{

```
Backup-Sqldatabase -ServerInstance  $server -Database  $item -BackupFile $backupfile
```

}